# Sketch the trajectories of the general solution in the phase plane.

Tags: calculus

In an earlier question part I was asked to find the general solution of a differential equation and found this to be $$4(y-x)^2+(y+x)^2=c$$

Next I'm asked to sketch trajectories of the general solution in the phase plane. I know that this is the equation of an ellipse but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take the implicit derivative of your general solution, $4(y-x)^2+(y+x)^2=c$, we derive the differential equation:

$$\tag 1 y' =  \dfrac{6 y-10 x}{10 y-6 x}$$

If we draw a direction field plot of $(1)$, we have ellipses as:

[image]

Now we are asked to sketch trajectories of the general solution onto the phase plane.

We can implicitly draw various solutions for some values of $c$, for example, if we randomly choose $c = 15$, we can draw an implicit plot for $4(y-x)^2+(y+x)^2=15$ and arrive at:

[image]

If we do this a few times, we can see that the various solutions are all ellipses that overlay onto the direction fields plot. In other words, we are effectively choosing different random initial conditions for these actual solution curves. If we now take a few of these and show them with the direction field plot, we have:

[image]

Comment: So with the second plot (the one where you looked at $c=15$), how would you sketch that without graphing software? I guess what I'm asking is what are the key points you get from the equation that allows you to sketch it?

Comment: You would pick a bunch of $x$ values, and for "each" one solve the quadratic for the two $y$ values until you have enough points to draw the ellipse. Also not that I chose $x$ values that are actually in the range of the direction field plot I drew, that is $-5 \le x \le 5$, although nothing would stop you from choosing a much larger range.